# Admob giving low fill rate

Tags: admob, facebook-audience-network

i have an admob account and it has been giving me very low fill rates (3-4%) overall. There is a voilation in the account that says the quality of traffic is not good. Is there anything I can do at my end to fix it?

At the same time audience network is working just fine.

I am asking if i can do any implementation level change that can help me get good fill rate.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about. Google does many things to checks your traffic quality.
And in most of the cases admob account gets terminated without giving any proper reason to user.

I had started exploring Facebook Audience Network in combination with Admob to maximize my revenue.

Here are some useful links

http://hackerseve.com/android-integrating-facebook-audience-network-fan/

http://hackerseve.com/android-using-together-admob-and-facebook-audience-network/